# Parsing JSON output by splitting by some special character or character sequence

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

Some logging libraries write JSON strings to files and then parse them.
I am writing a library for integration tests and want to know what the best way is to split the JSON strings so that I can create an array of the strings and then parse them one at a time.

This would be done like so:

```
var path = require('path');
var filePath = path.resolve(appRootPath + '/' + 'test/output/test1.txt');
var rstream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

var data = '';

rstream
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    })
    .on('end', function () {  // done
        var array = String(dataLength).split(';'); //spit the big string into an array of strings by some token

        doTheThing(array.filter(function (item) {   //filter and parse the array element by element
            return item && item.length > 0;
        }).map(function (item) {
            return JSON.parse(String(item));
        }));

    });
```

Below, I just put in semi-colons as a delineating character, however that won't be good enough for the obvious reasons.

So I am looking to parse something like this big string below (forgive the nonsense words like 'dogs' and 'cats'):

```
{"testId":21,"desc":"cats 1"};{"testId":18,"desc":"dogs 1"};{"testId":1,"desc":"makes stuff 1","error":{}};{"testId":22,"desc":"cats 2"};{"testId":19,"desc":"dogs 2"};{"testId":2,"desc":"makes stuff 2","error":{}};{"testId":20,"tests":[{"testId":21,"type":"it-standard","desc":"cats 1","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":22,"type":"it-standard","desc":"cats 2","complete":false,"error":null}],"testsParallel":[],"loopTests":[],"children":[],"error":null};{"testId":17,"tests":[{"testId":18,"type":"it-standard","desc":"dogs 1","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":19,"type":"it-standard","desc":"dogs 2","complete":false,"error":null}],"testsParallel":[],"loopTests":[],"children":[{"testId":20}],"error":null};{"testId":3,"desc":"makes stuff 2","error":null};{"testId":4,"desc":"makes stuff 2","error":{}};{"testId":10,"desc":"makes stuff 1","error":{}};{"testId":11,"desc":"makes stuff 2","error":null};{"testId":12,"desc":"makes stuff 3","error":{}};{"testId":14,"desc":"makes stuff 44","error":{}};{"testId":15,"desc":"makes stuff 888","error":{}};{"testId":16,"desc":"makes stuff 999","error":{}};{"testId":6,"desc":"makes stuff chard","error":{}};{"testId":7,"desc":"makes stuff heeee","error":{}};{"testId":8,"desc":"makes stuff raaa","error":{}};{"testId":0,"tests":[{"testId":1,"type":"it-standard","desc":"makes stuff 1","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":2,"type":"it-standard","desc":"makes stuff 2","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":3,"type":"it-standard","desc":"makes stuff 2","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":4,"type":"it-standard","desc":"makes stuff 2","complete":false,"error":null}],"testsParallel":[{"testId":9,"tests":[{"testId":10,"type":"it-parallel","desc":"makes stuff 1","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":11,"type":"it-parallel","desc":"makes stuff 2","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":12,"type":"it-parallel","desc":"makes stuff 3","complete":false,"error":null}],"type":"ParallelTestSet"},{"testId":13,"tests":[{"testId":14,"type":"it-parallel","desc":"makes stuff 44","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":15,"type":"it-parallel","desc":"makes stuff 888","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":16,"type":"it-parallel","desc":"makes stuff 999","complete":false,"error":null}],"type":"ParallelTestSet"}],"loopTests":[{"testId":5,"tests":[{"testId":6,"type":"it-loop","desc":"makes stuff chard","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":7,"type":"it-loop","desc":"makes stuff heeee","complete":false,"error":null},{"testId":8,"type":"it-loop","desc":"makes stuff raaa","complete":false,"error":null}],"type":"LoopTestSet"}],"children":[{"testId":17}],"error":null};
```

I need a clever way to delineate the would-be JS objects with some special character that can never appear in the output (I *can* control what ends up in the output, but that might require that I filter the end user's data that ends up on disk).

How is this done? Is there some super special character or character sequence I can use? Or is there a 'cleverer' way to do it that I am not thinking of?

Comment: Is it possible for you to store the tests in an array: [{},{},...,{}]? This would make parsing easier on you, as you'd be able to use built in methods to loop through your data.

Comment: yeah I could do that I guess, I would just parse the whole thing at once, there will never be that much data, so should be fine

Comment: Generally speaking, log entries each appear on their own line in a log file, thereby making the systems' line separation sequence (`\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`, etc.) the separator.

Comment: yeah, I will probably want to include the newline characters, so hopefully JSON.parse can ignore those, I will find out soon, because I can't blindly strip them out because then I will strip the newline chars out of the output itself

Comment: You're going to want to go with the array solution then. If there's not really any guarantee that any given character/sequence won't show up in a given tests definition, I don't know that you have an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

With JSON.parse() its possible to create an object out of a string.
Maybe try it this way:

- read the JSON file as a string
- split the string into an array: string.split(';');
- and now parse all the array entries in a loop with JSON.parse

Or just make an array in the JSON File and parse this complete thing

Comment: thanks Tim, but this question is about how to split the big unparseable string into separate parseable JSON strings; as you can see my OP has the formula you specify, but it will falter as soon as the user includes a semicolon character inside the output

Comment: you're right. Haven't thought about this. Make an array, like bstockwell said.